# How can I "ORDER BY" using SQLSelect?

Tags: databaselink, query

A pretty straightforward problem, you would think, but I cannot seem to find the answer in the [documentation for SQLSelect](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/DatabaseLink/ref/SQLSelect.html).

The query I want to run is the following:

```
SELECT id, measurement, timestamp FROM myTable WHERE id IN (1, 2) ORDER BY timestamp
```

The *Mathematica* query I have so far is:

```
SQLSelect[dbConn,
    "myTable",
    {"id", "measurement", "timeStamp"},
    SQLMemberQ[{1, 2}, SQLColumn["id"]]
]
```

But I cannot seem to find an option to insert the `ORDER BY` requirement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use "SortingColumns" in SQLSelect or simply use the SQL statement inside SQLExecute.

In the second case you simply write the SQL statement in the string:

```
SQLExecute[dbConn, "SELECT id, measurement, timestamp FROM myTable WHERE id IN (1, 2) ORDER BY timestamp"]
```

And you are returned triplets with {id, measurement, timestamp}.